# How do I change sort order for release versions in JIRA/Greenhopper planning?

Tags: sorting, version, jira, jira-agile

I've created several release versions in JIRA (the closest thing I could find to a "sprint" functionality) but I cannot for the life of me figure out how it decides what order to put them in, nor how to change it.  I thought maybe it would sort them chronologically by start date, or release date, but no dice.

All I want to do is make a bunch of versions so I can assign user stories, but have them appear in the planning view chronologically.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you might want to look at the Greenhopper plugin for JIRA.
Anyway, you can order versions by going to Admin, Projects, your Project, Manage Versions and use the up and down arrows

Answer (score 3):

Go to the Versions section of the main page for your project.  Because you have permissions to create versions, there should be a "Manage Versions" link in the top right of the content area.

This screen is probably where you added the versions to begin with.
In the table is a "Schedule" column which allows you to change the order of the versions, but be careful, this list is showing versions chronologically backwards.  In other words, the first/next sprint should be at the bottom.

Comment: this is the utterly right answer. I have no idea why atlassian decided that the list should be back-to-front, but there you have it.

Comment: I have the same problem as the OP and it appears that your answer should be the correct one, but I only have Name, Description and Release Date as columns on the Manage Versions page (unless I'm looking at the wrong page!) Is this because I'm using out-of-date versions of JIRA (4.4.1) and GreenHopper (5.7.1) or is there another reason? (I have full permissions on the project, as far as I can tell - I can add versions OK)

Comment: one of the reasons back-to-front works best is so in a JIRA view you can sort `fixVersion DESC` and have the Issues with no `fixVersion` collate to the bottom

Answer (score 0):

> ...but be careful, this list is showing versions chronologically backwards. In other words, the first/next sprint should be at the bottom.

Is there a way to reverse that? To have the first/next sprint at the top? For example:

- Version 7.2

  - 7.2 Sprint 1 (May 1 - May 31)
  - 7.2 Sprint 2 (June 1 - June 30)
  - 7.2 Sprint 3 (July 1 - July 31)
- Version 7.3 (August 1 - August 31)

  - 7.3 Sprint 1 (September 1 - September 30)
  - 7.3 Sprint 2 (October 1 - October 31)
  - 7.3 Sprint 3 (November 1 - November 30)

Answer (score 0):

In Greenhopper the order is not following the settings that apply for normal JIRA, but the ordering is on "release date" with "sooner" ones being ordered above "later" ones and ones without release date are added at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

On the Releases page, you can sort the versions/releases by dragging the three line icons (located on the left hand side of the releases list) up and down.